# Send SOAP Request in Robotframework without WSDL

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, robotframework, suds

I am trying to send a SOAP request in Robotframework using SudsLibrary.

It works fine if I have a WSDL file (locally or remotely), but in this specific situation, I don't have any kind of WSDL. Just a URL for an application endpoint.

Note: I tried to send it with SoapUI without WSDL (only with URL) and it just works fine, and in another languages I can do it too (like Ruby+Savon for example).

Now, any ideas how can I accomplish that only with an URL and Suds? or even with another library?

Thank you very much.

Example code (that throws error 500 when using a "non WSDL" URL instead a true WSLD):

```
#Example URL: "http://IP:PORT/exampleAction"

${wsdl}=  set variable    ${CURDIR}/WSDLs/CreateService.WSDL
${wsdl_operation}=    set variable    X.Asset.UpdateNotification

${msg}=   Keyword That Returns Some Kind of XML

Create Soap Client   ${wsdl}
${raw_msg}=     Create Raw Soap Message    ${msg}

${result}=      Call Soap Method    ${wsdl_operation}    ${raw_msg}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you get the WSDL from the URL you have, by adding ?WSDL ?
For example: "http://IP:PORT/exampleAction?WSDL"

You can use RequestsLibrary to send a XML file to the service.

Comment: Adding "?WSDL" throws an error but "Requests" works fine. Thank you very much for the solution.